# Verifying very high Riemann zeros.

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

Using some newly derived formulas for the n-th Riemann zero on the critical line,
I calculated the 10^(10^6)'th zero to 1 million decimal places rather easily.
Can anyone suggest an alternative way to verify this?
I'm confident it is correct,  but it cannot be simply verified with Mathematica for instance since it cannot compute the Riemann zeta function for such a large ordinate.

The result is here:  http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~leclair/10106zero.pdf

Comment: Why not try to use your method to calculate some zeros in ranges that *are* already known, e.g. the $10^{22}$th zero.  See http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/zeta.10to22.pdf

Comment: We already checked that the method works in known ranges,  in particular we checked 10^5 zeros around the 10^9 -th and some around 10^22 -th,  but I don't think any are known beyond that.   Do you know?

Comment: For instance,  for the 10^22 -th zero I obtain 1.370919909931995308227*10^21  which is correct to the number of digits shown (comparing with Odlyzko).

Comment: I would recommend directly contacting an expert, perhaps Andrew Booker and his student (now post-doc) David Platt, both at Bristol.

Comment: could this be verified with arbitrary precision code like http://fredrikj.net/arb/

Comment: Is your method anything more than an asymptotic evaluation? Eg, you get 22 digits around $10^{22}$, one million around $10^{10^6}$, etc. but I think this is rather easy to do, as you are essentially just computing with LambertW (as the writeup says). Better to get 1000 digits around $10^{100}$? Is all you are saying is that the error in zero-counting by $f(T)={T\over 2\pi}\log {T\over 2\pi e}$ is calculable (with bounds), and then you invert? Eg, $f^{-1}(10^{22})$ is essentially as you list.

Comment: Can you compute $Z(t)$ or just zeros? Finding large $|Z(t)|$ on the critical line for t large might be of interest.

Comment: Conder,  yes it is an asymptotic expansion.  However it is an approximation to an *exact* equation we derived satisfied by each zero.  The latter involves arg \zeta on the line,  which is of order one.  When you drop this arg term,  then the equation can be simply inverted in terms of LambertW and all digits before the decimal point are accurate.  We didn't simply invert the counting formula f(T) but derived the equation for the n-th zero directly,  so it not so easy,  unless you assume the RH.

Comment: joro:   no we cannot compute Z(t) for such high values.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert by any means, but I think one way is to use the argument principle: numerically evaluate a contour integral of the logarithmic derivative around your zero.  The answer is going to be an integer, so if you can provably approximate it you can prove numerically that it is one.  This would require high-precision approximations to the logarithmic derivative.

[Update:]

I just realized that you are simply trying to find a single zero, not to count the zeroes in an interval.  This is done by finding sign changes. Try the discussions of Turing's work by [Hejhal--Odlyzko](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/turing.zeta.pdf) and [Booker](http://www.ams.org/notices/200610/fea-booker.pdf): set $\Gamma_\mathbb{R}(s) = \pi^{-s/2}\Gamma(\frac{s}{2})$, and $\xi(s) = \Gamma_\mathbb{R}(s)\zeta(s)$.  By the functional equation, $\xi(s)$ is real on the critical line, so $\Xi(t) = \xi(\frac{1}{2}+it)$ is a real-valued function of $t$.  To show your zero is accurate you need to find a sign change (conjecturally your zero, like all other zeroes, is simple): if $\gamma$ is the height of your zero and you'd to show it is accurate to within $\epsilon$ you need to show that $\Xi(\gamma\pm\epsilon)$ have distinct signs.  Now the $\Gamma$ factor is very small, but dividing by its *absolute value* won't affect signs.  The Riemann-Siegel formula (see Booker's paper) allows you to accurately evaluate the zeta function at those points.

Comment: Lior,  nice suggestion.  But as you point out, one requires high-precision approximations to the log derivative.  This would have to be an analytic approximation,  since numerical programs like Mathematica can't deal with such high values.   Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use high-precision numerical libraries.

Comment: Thanks Lior.  I've looked into what you are referring to involving Riemann Siegel.   These are the well-known Gram points,  which are close but not the same as this lambertW based formula.  Also,  Gram's law is known to fail for about 1/4 of the zeros,  so I'm not sure it is enough to look at these sign changes.    I'll look at Booker's paper,  thanks again.